# How to make sure a MySQL database exists before running Node.js app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm, sequelize.js

I have a Node.js/Express based app that is using Sequelize to talk to a MySQL server. What is the best way to ensure that a specific database exists before starting the app using `npm start`? I guess it would be some kind of one-time database initialization script that runs `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo;` - I am just not sure where to put it and how to hook it up to a lifecycle event.

Comment: Just try to connect to database. If database doesn't exists, you will get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) npm supports the "scripts" property of the package.json script, one of which is `prestart`, so you could have a package.json

```
{ "scripts" :
  { 
  "prestart" : "node scripts/mysqlCheck.js", 
  "start" : "node index.js"
  }
}
```

then in that `mysqlCheck.js` have your MySQL DB checks. Then when you run `npm start` the `prestart` script will be run before `index.js`.